# get un-child elements

Tags: jquery, html

I have mega menu working and now I want to get all those `h3` tags which does not have children `ul` after it.

this is the html of that `li` which have children with it

```
<li id="megamenu-mlid-370" class="megamenu-slot megamenu-slot-0 odd half-1 leaf-0 first  first">
    <h3 class="megamenu-slot-title"><a href="/kcompute/" class="active">IT Management Solutions</a></h3>
    <ul class="megamenu-items ">
        <li id="megamenu-mlid-373" class="megamenu-item megamenu-item-0 odd half-1 leaf-0 first  first"><a href="/kcompute/" class="active">Web Portal</a></li>
        <li id="megamenu-mlid-374" class="megamenu-item megamenu-item-1 even half-1 leaf-1 "><a href="/kcompute/" class="active">Document Management</a></li>
        <li id="megamenu-mlid-381" class="megamenu-item megamenu-item-2 odd half-1 leaf-2 "><a href="/kcompute/" class="active">Content Management </a></li>
        <li id="megamenu-mlid-382" class="megamenu-item megamenu-item-3 even half-1 leaf-3 "><a href="/kcompute/" class="active">Knowledge Management</a></li>
        <li id="megamenu-mlid-383" class="megamenu-item megamenu-item-4 odd half-1 leaf-4 "><a href="/kcompute/" class="active">Trading and Brokerage</a></li>
        <li id="megamenu-mlid-384" class="megamenu-item megamenu-item-5 even half-2 leaf-5 "><a href="/kcompute/" class="active">Enterprise Resource Planning</a></li>
        <li id="megamenu-mlid-385" class="megamenu-item megamenu-item-6 odd half-2 leaf-6 "><a href="/kcompute/" class="active">Simulator Development </a></li>
        <li id="megamenu-mlid-386" class="megamenu-item megamenu-item-7 even half-2 leaf-7 "><a href="/kcompute/" class="active">Data Management</a></li>
        <li id="megamenu-mlid-387" class="megamenu-item megamenu-item-8 odd half-2 leaf-8 last  last"><a href="/kcompute/" class="active">Telecommunication</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

and now this is the html of that li which does not have children `ul`

```
<li id="megamenu-mlid-419" class="megamenu-slot megamenu-slot-0 odd half-1 leaf-0 first  first">
    <h3 class="megamenu-slot-title"><a href="/kcompute/" class="active">Jobs</a></h3>
</li>
```

In javascript I have `megaBins` function which returns all `ul`'s

I want a jQuery function to add a class `no-items` in which there are no children's.

Regards

Comment: Do you want a function that generates HTML or that filter your DOM ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("ul.megamenu > li").each(function() {
    if ($(this).find("ul").length == 0) {
        $(this).addClass("no-items");
    }
});
```

You will most likely need to change the `ul.megamenu` selector to match the `ul` of your megadropdown - I just took a guess at what is was.

Comment: thank you . your code worked for me. I'm missing my logic thanks for your time. AND THANKS TO ALL PEOPLE ABOVE.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Try the :has selector combined with not. http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

```
$("#megamenu > li").not("#megamenu > li:has(> ul)").addClass("no-items");
```

And here is a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NSr7S/7/

Answer (score 0):

you can write a custom jQuery function as well.

```
jQuery.fn.checkChildren = function () {
    var validChilds = 'li,h3'
    $(this).each (function () {
        if ($(this).find(validChilds).length == 0) {
            $(this).addClass('no-items');
        }
    });
}

$(function () {
    $('div#liWrapper').children('li').checkChildren(); 
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/T6K6q/